# main listview in android

Tags: android, listview

In main list if suppose there are 3 topics if i click one topic it should expand list in that i should select one sub topic and if click the 2nd topic in the main list it should expand in that i should select one sub topic and if i click 3rd topic in the main list it should expand in that i should one sub topic.... By selecting like this three topics and then if give submit after that it should the related contents based on the three topics...can help me for this concept can you give example coding for this...

Comment: can we have some code please !?

Comment: @Ramkiran at one point you ask for WTHT and at another point you are replying. First let them ask properly with possible code/snaps/logcat output.

Comment: @PareshMayani, may be your correct. I just visit the Prasanth Kc profile after ask him for trying, there I search his previous question and understand his requirement and posted the answer..

Answer (score 3):

Check these Related examples

- [Expandable list and checkboxes revisited](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2010/12/expandable-list-and-checkboxes.html)
- [ExpandableListView and CheckBox in Android](http://prativas.wordpress.com/2012/06/22/expandablelistview-and-checkbox-in-android/)
- [Android BaseExpandableListAdapter](http://blog.csdn.net/zhyooo123/article/details/6254180)

Comment: ,pareshmayani, i want to work out with this concept. im new to android. just know simple list view. i need example codings for this concept...